# Input type=month to display month in another language

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using input type = month to display Month and year in ionic. I would like to display the month in german (lang='de') instead of english.

```
<input lang='de' class='month-text-box' type="month" [(ngModel)]="month" readonly>
```

I tried the above method but did not work, Is there a way to achieve this? I actually have a functionality as shown in the image to navigate between months using the left and right arrow. This should display month in german instead of english. (eg. Mai instead of May)

[image]

Comment: You want to do this without changing the language of your whole document to German?

Comment: Yes, all the app is entirely in german.

Comment: As the answer says, I would expect that consumers would have their browsers' language set to German so it would already be identified as such. You should be setting the `lang` attribute on the `html` element anyway. You might need to look into a globalization plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, this is up to the browser's configured locale settings. You can consider implementing it yourself, but I'd guess anyone using a German version of your website (especially if you offer an English version) probably has their browser configured to use German.

Comment: Actually this is for an app. So the browser's language wouldn't help :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it cant help but you can use [`ion-datetime`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime):

```
//pt-br
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>DDD. MMM DD, YY (custom locale)</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime value="1995-04-15" min="1990-02" max="2000"
    [dayShortNames]="dom, seg, ter, qua, qui, sex, sab"
    displayFormat="DDD. MMM DD, YY"
    monthShortNames="jan, fev, mar, abr, mai, jun, jul, ago, set, out, nov, dez"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```